# Putnam 2022 B1 Solution verification

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, contest-math

**Problem statement:**

Suppose that $P(x) = a_1x + a_2x^2 + ··· + a_nx^n$
is a polynomial with integer coefficients, with $a_1$ odd. Suppose that $e^{P(x)} = b_0 +b_1x+b_2x^2 +···$ for all $x$. Prove that $b_k$ is nonzero for all $k ≥ 0$

**My solution:**

Let $f(x)=e^{P(x)}=\sum_{r=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(r)}(0)x^r}{r!}$ where $f^{(r)}$ denotes the $r$th derivative of $f$. (This is the Taylor series expansion rather than the exponential series expansion).

Note that by differentiating $f(x)$ we find that $f^{(r)}(x)$ is of the form $Q_r(x)e^{P(x)}$ where $Q_r(x)$ is a polynomial formed from a combination of derivatives of $P(x)$.

For instance, $f^{(1)}(x)=P^\prime(x)e^{P(x)}\implies Q_1(x)=P^\prime(x)$

$f^{(2)}(x)=[P^{\prime\prime(x)}+(P^\prime(x))^2]e^{P(x)}\implies Q_2(x)=P^{\prime\prime(x)}+(P^\prime(x))^2$

and so on.

The $b_k$ coefficients which we are required to show to be nonzero are of the form

$\frac{f^{(r)}(0)}{r!}=\frac{Q_r(0)e^{P(0)}}{r!}$

(from the Taylor series expansion), and since $\frac{e^{P(0)}}{r!}\neq0$, it suffices to show that $Q_r(0)\neq0 \ \forall r$. We will show that $Q_r(0)$ can be expressed as a sum of even integers and a single odd integer, meaning it is odd an thus nonzero.

We proceed by induction. It is easy to see that $Q_1(0)=P^\prime(0)=a_1e^{P(0)}\neq0$.

For the inductive step, firstly note that

$P^{(r)}(0)=\begin{cases} 
      r!a_r & r=1,2,...,n \\
      0 & r>n
   \end{cases}$

Thus, since we are given that $a_1$ is odd, and $r!$ contains a factor of $2$ for $r>1$, it follows that $P^{(r)}(0)$ is odd for $r=1$ and even for $r>1$.

Now the $Q(x)$ polynomials as we have seen can each be expressed as a sum of terms whose factors are the derivatives of $P(x)$. We claim that $Q_r(0)$ can be expressed (for all $r$) as a sum of terms all of which are even integers apart from a single power of $P^{(1)}(0)$ which is odd, and hence that the sum overall is odd.

$Q_1(x)=P^{(1)}(x)$ and so $Q_1(0)$ satisfies this requirement.

Suppose $Q_m(0)$ also satisfies the requirement.

We differentiate $f^{(r)}(x)$ to find that

$Q_{m+1}(x)=Q_m^\prime(x)+P^\prime(x)Q_m(x)$

During differentiation, the single term in $Q_m^\prime(x)$ which was initially a power of $P^{(1)}(x)$ acquires a factor of $P^{(2)}(x)$, and thus becomes even within the term $Q_m^\prime(x)$. On the other hand, within the term $P^\prime(x)Q_m(x)$, the single odd term simply increases its power by one, and thus remains odd.

Hence, by induction, $Q_m(0)$ has a unique odd integer term and is thus nonzero for all $m$. This completes the proof.

One concern I have is whether it's ok to use Taylor series in this way to express a function that was already a different kind of infinite series? (I haven't done this before). Also just in general wondering whether there is anything else about the proof that's insufficient (though if I'm not allowed to ask that here - the rules aren't exactly clear - please do tell me and I'll go somewhere else).

Comment: The $P(x)^k$ term in the solution you linked appears to just be separated from the rest of the summation as a matter of convenience (since that term in particular is referenced in the following paragraph). In general they are summing over all $P(x)^n$ that could possibly result in an $x^k$ term.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean by "$Q_r(x)$ contains a unique term with a factor of $P'(x)$" and "has a unique odd term". It would probably help to actually write somewhere the sum you're referring to.

Comment: I can't follow your proof I am afraid.  For example, I'm not able to parse out e.g., "where $Q_r(x)$ contains a unique term with a factor of $P′(x)$".

Comment: Given the numerous solution verification posts you're making, please read [this meta thread on how to ask a good proof-verification question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35592/how-to-ask-a-good-proof-verification-question?cb=1).

Comment: Regarding your last question, that's the definition of expoentiation. IE $EXP [P(x)] = 1/0! + P(x)/1! + P^2(x) / 2! + P^3(x) / 3! + \ldots $. $\quad$ It's not great that the Putnam didn't define what $e^{P(x) } $ is. Where did you get your definition from?

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful comments and I apologise for the poor readability before, I've gone to some lengths to improve the clarity. Calvin - I wasn't using exponentiation but Taylor series, although I'm not sure it's valid?

Comment: The Putnam is notorious for being very strict with their grading. I've never graded it, so I can't conclusively speak to what is "insufficient". It's definitely helpful to state how you're arriving at the result, and maybe even the conditions so the grader can be confident you know what you're talking about. $\quad$ IF Putnam defined exponentiation (which they didn't), then I personally would not accept the Taylor series form without further justification (of convergence, accuracy, etc) even though polynomials should be "nice enough".